# Oracle Apex: Prevent see all tabs while Page Reloading

Tags: tabs, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I'm using Oracle Apex 19.1

I got a page with 4 tabs in a Region Display Selector. When it comes up to a page reload you can see all tabs while the page is loading. It's not a second but you see the content of all tabs among themselves flashing.

I tried to set a staticID on the Region Display Selector and use it in the css with `display:none` with a Dynamic Action on Page Load i call the show True Action on the Region but it's still the same effect with all tabs flashing.

Is there a method i can prevent this?

Thanks for any advise and help

Answer (score 2):

I avoided this by putting a custom attribute in the region.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the server side condition to
Item != Value
for a particular hidden value
then create a page load process to set the value.
Then the regions should appear after the page loads.